# How to pass external groovy script in pom.xml (Soapui and Maven Integration)

Tags: maven, groovy, soapui

my pom.xml is here with project.xml and soapui-setting.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>SOAPUI</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SOAPUI</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>SOAPUI-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <outputFolder>reports\</outputFolder>
                            <testSuite>UVConnect_Users</testSuite>
                            <testCase>TC_DECE_00001_UV_UserCreate_Adult_FAU_TOU_NotAccepted</testCase>
                            <settingsFile>C:\Users\omkar.khatavkar\soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
                            <soapuiProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>soapui.scripting.library</name>
                                    <value>C:\Scripts</value>
                                </property>
                            </soapuiProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

but after giving mvn test as maven target then it gives failure as it does not understand.

Is there any way I can pass external written groovy scripts into Soap ui Maven command line target ?

```
00:25:00,371 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class dbUtils.dbUtils
 @ line 15, column 9.
   def a = new dbUtils.dbUtils(log,dBHost);
           ^`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added path for Script and Ext folder which i was missing. here is my updated pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>SOAPUI</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>SOAPUI</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>11.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>SOAPUI-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <outputFolder>reports\</outputFolder>
                        <testSuite>UVConnect_Users</testSuite>
                        <testCase>TC_DECE_00001_UV_UserCreate_Adult_FAU_TOU_NotAccepted</testCase>
                        <settingsFile>C:\Users\omkar.khatavkar\soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
                        <soapuiProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>soapui.scripting.library</name>
                                <value>C:\Scripts</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>soapui.ext.libraries</name>
                                <value>C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-Pro-4.6.1\lib</value>
                            </property>
                        </soapuiProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... after giving mvn test ...

That should be: `mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:test`, right?

> Is there any way I can pass external written groovy scripts into Soap ui Maven command line target ?

There are two options:

1. If you have the -Pro version (which from your pom seems like you do *not*), you can use the [Script Library](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html). Be careful how you specify the path, so that it works on your CI machine!
2. Compile the scripts to a jar and specify it as a [dependency in the soapui-maven-plugin in your pom](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html#5-plugin-settings).

You might need to read through the [SoapUI docs](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html).

Comment: I edited the pom.xml and also tried with the target that you have mentioned. still seeing the same error. Do I required to have license for this.

Comment: You need to describe in detail: 1. Where is you scrip in relation to your project. 2. How are you specifying the script location in your project. 3. Does it work from the SoapUI GUI.

Comment: It got worked after doing some more changes related to setting ext and script folder.